# WebAPI, [FromBody] string, application/json, Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI project (c#) and i test it with my page (Index.cshtml):

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function GetData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:0000/api/test/test/cox/Test",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify("Hello!!!"),
            crossDomain: true,
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
            headers: { User: "test", Password: "test" },
            success: function (q, w, e) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(q));
            },
            error: function (q, w, e) {
                alert("error: " + w);
            }
        });
    }

</script>

<p>
    <button onclick="GetData()">GetData</button>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This page call my method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<СompositeType>))]
public HttpResponseMessage Test(string cox, [FromBody] string str)
{
   ...    
}
```

and i get the error: 415 "Unsupported Media Type". I read about this error and somebody is talking that `contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8'` will solve the problem. I know that attribute [FromBody] call to `contentType: 'application/json'` for transformation , but i don't undestand why i have the error 415.

Comment: It should be "application/json; charset=utf-8" (note ";" instead of ",")

Comment: It is don't work, i get error 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: Maybe, but specific problem in your question is now solved, now you have another problem.

Comment: I don't think so, because if i write `data: JSON.stringify(),` i call method `Test`.

Comment: Why using JSON for non object data? I also think you should try using `data: JSON.stringify({ str: "Hello!!!"})` so the httphandler can match parameter name (I'm not shure cause I ususally use models for transfering data to/from APIs)...

Comment: If i use `data: JSON.stringify({str:"Hello!!!"})` then i get error 415 again. 
If i use `data: JSON.stringify("Hello!!!")` without `[FromBody]` then i get error 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Evk, you are right, but i don't undestand why `contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8'` works then `data: JSON.stringify(),`

Comment: @Джирайя I guess because result of `JSON.stringify()` is `undefined`, so you are not sending any body, and so content type plays no role (even if it's invalid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but it is a little cheat. (I want to say: "Thank you!)", for 
the answers).

**The first**. I changed this:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({"str":"Hello!!!"}),
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

**The second**. I changed this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<СompositeType>))]
public HttpResponseMessage Test(string cox, [FromBody] Test str)
{
   ...    
}
```

**The third**. I added a new class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string str { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: What is `СompositeType` or what is the name space for this

Answer (score 0):

Try change from [FromBody] to [FromForm]